# pip install terraform_utils failing

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, terraform

Trying to install terraform_utils with pip on  python 2.7  on Mac.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-p0O4_9/terraform-utils/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-p0O4_9/terraform-utils/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-30t_an
     cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-p0O4_9/terraform-utils/
Complete output (6 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip-install-p0O4_9/terraform-utils/setup.py", line 8
    def read_file(path: Union[str, Path]) -> str:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

can anyone help with the above error? not able to figure out what's missing!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are running this code with Python2.7 but it is supported only by Python 3.5+. This syntax refers to static typing, more information here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html